# Endpoint startup notification in Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Using Microprofile Liberty server, I need to notify another service on startup that will callback my service on https endpoint. By the way the https endpoint is not always started and inbound service may receive some connection errors.
Options I could imagine are: retry on other service or verify https availability doing rest calls before notifying other service.
Is there any built in way to be notified that endpoint is started or available using MBean notification or CDI event ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on the use case, but it seems like you need to perform an operation (attempting to call another service) on startup? If that's the case, you could try using a CDI bean that listens to the startup event like this:

```java
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Initialized;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

@ApplicationScoped
public class StartupNotification {

  public void notifyOtherService(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object context) {
    // this will be invoked on application startup
    // run code here to notify the other service on startup
  }

}
```

Comment: This notification occurs before server http endpoint is enabled. So if we notify other service at this moment the other service will not be able to contact our service and will receive a connection error. We are running in kubernetes so I may be we should notifiy other services only when our readiness probe is invoked.